# Can't open txt file from qrc

Tags: c++, qt, qml, txt

I'm working on qml application and in Qt part I've got class TxtLoader, to read data from txt files and send it to QML part. I've created qrc file, added d.txt file and tried to open it:

```
    QFile file(":/d.txt");

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

        qDebug() << file.errorString();

    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString text;
    text.clear();

    while(!in.atEnd()) {

        QString line = in.readLine();
        text += line;

    }
```

File d.txt is in qrc list, but I've got an error: "No such file or directory".
I've already tried different ways for the file path: ":/d.txt", "qrc:/d.txt", "file:///d.txt", "d.txt", "qrc:///d.txt", the only way it works is with the full path, but I need it to work with url from qrc.
I've tried to do the same thing with Qt Widgets app, with no QML, and it works just fine with ":/d.txt" path. What could be the issue here?

Comment: We can only help with the answer to 3 questions: what is the content of your qrc file? are you sure the qrc file is compiled into a C++ file? and the C++ file is compiled into your executable?

Comment: Are you sure that `d.txt` is in the root of the structure on the qrc file?

Comment: What do you mean by "the only way it works is with the full path"?

Comment: I mean path from the root: "/home/.../Qt Projects/Project/d.txt"

Comment: @EL96cpp Please answer the questions asked by Atmo, we cannot help you if we don't have enough context to understand the problem. From your limited description, we can only assume that you didn't properly include/register the resource file in your program.

Comment: You're right, problem was that my qrc file wasn't compiled into C++, adding `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` to my CMakeLists.txt helped, thank you guys!

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in qrc file not compiling to C++ file, adding `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` to `CMakeLists.txt` solved my problem.

Another way is to add resources to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
qt_add_qml_module(appName
    URI appName
    VERSION 1.0
    ...
    RESOURCES Texts/d.txt 
)
```

And then you can open it using this path:

```
QFile file(":/appName/Texts/d.txt");
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but this is not the only way. If you properly create your qrc file and add the resource in CMake it will work. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468413/qt-resources-files-with-cmake-and-autorcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468413/qt-resources-files-with-cmake-and-autorcc)

Comment: I expect someone downvoted both question and answer because you asked a question that was unanswerable by us because you left out required information that we didn't have. Then you later self-answered still without giving us the required information.